# order at will paragraph items of different paragraph type

Tags: paragraphs

On the module description it says :

> They [the end-users] can then add as many Paragraph items as you allowed them to and
>   reorder them at will.

I have created two paragraph types and created 2 corresponding paragraph fields.

I dont see how the end-users can re-order one to another in /node/nid/edit?

https://screenshots.firefox.com/ZUCvIvfQ5iHDqW0R/d7-mathieu.univ-amu.fr

Is there a way to allow end-users to create as many paragraphs as they want and reorder them at will , even between different paragraph-type.

For example being able to create one page with:

> -paragraph-item-type1
>
> -paragraph-item-type2
>
> -paragraph-item-type1
>
> -paragraph-item-type1
>
> -paragraph-item-type2

And another page with

> -paragraph-item-type2
>
> -paragraph-item-type2
>
> -paragraph-item-type2
>
> -paragraph-item-type1

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question, but could you not simply use one paragraph field and allow both paragraph types in it?

Comment: You did create an entity reference or entity revision reference field as described in the module's documentation? - Don't forget to make it a multi-value field and choose the right widget.

Comment: thanks 4k4, i have been stupid and did not think of that option.if u want to make that response i will select yours as the right one since u were first responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, you have to create only one paragraph field on the node, and allow both paragraph types for that specific field (default setting is allow all paragraph types anyways). Then editors can rearrange all paragraphs within that field at will.